# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException, syntax to use near ''3)' at line 1

Tags: java, jdbc

Error is:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''3)' at line 1

Code is:

```
fecha = +jFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (jFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + jFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println(fecha);
        String parte = cmbParte.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println(parte);
        try {

            Conexion.ins.execute("insert into registros(id_registro, job, ip, id_parte, fecha, id_inspector, id_descripcion, piezasrech, piezasinsp, id_disposicion, id_area, id_responsable, id_estacion)"
                    + " values(0,'" + txtOrder.getText() + "','" + txtIP.getText() + "','" + id_parte
                    + "','" + fecha + "','" + id_inspector + "','" + id_descripcion
                    + "','" + txtPR.getText() + "','" + txtPI.getText() + "','" + id_disposicion
                    + "','" + id_area + "','" + id_responsable + "','" + id_estacion + ");");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro agregado con exito");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error al intentar agregar el Registro");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you print this string and give us result: "insert into registros(id_registro, job, ip, id_parte, fecha, id_inspector, id_descripcion, piezasrech, piezasinsp, id_disposicion, id_area, id_responsable, id_estacion)"
                    + " values(0,'" + txtOrder.getText() + "','" + txtIP.getText() + "','" + id_parte
                    + "','" + fecha + "','" + id_inspector + "','" + id_descripcion
                    + "','" + txtPR.getText() + "','" + txtPI.getText() + "','" + id_disposicion
                    + "','" + id_area + "','" + id_responsable + "','" + id_estacion + ");"

Comment: Have you tried to print the sql string before executing. Doing that will help you find the problem in your query string.

Comment: Please check the generated sql string, and run it once in the SQL IDE

Comment: it says the same error

Comment: i already prove the query into de MySQL and works perfectly, but the error is in the java app

Comment: The problem is that you're using common `Statement` that only receives a single `String` to execute the query, which is a bad approach. It would be better to use `PreparedStatement`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest dropping your current implementation of the `Conexion.ins.execute` method and replace it by one that uses a `PreparedStatement` instead and you can get rid of this concatenation problems that are hard to maintain and even worse, are prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

This is an example of the implementation using `PreparedStatement` and vararg argument for the parameters:

```
public void execute(String query, Object ... params) throws SQLException {
    //assumes you already have your Connection
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    int i = 1;
    for(Object param : params) {
        pstmt.setObject(i++, param);
    }
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    pstmt.close();
}
```

With this implementation, you can call the method in a more readable way for you and your coworkers:

```
String insertSQL = "insert into registros(id_registro, job, ip, id_parte, fecha,"
    + "id_inspector, id_descripcion, piezasrech, piezasinsp, "
    + "id_disposicion, id_area, id_responsable, id_estacion) "
    + "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
Conexion.ins.execute(insertSQL,
    txtOrder.getText(), txtIP.getText(), id_parte, fecha,
    id_inspector, id_descripcion, txtPR.getText(), txtPI.getText(),
    id_disposicion, id_area, id_responsable, id_estacion);
```

Comment: thank you very much. I did not know about that, will try to implement

Answer (score 1):

A <'> seems to be missing before closing parenthesis after id_estacion in `id_responsable + "','" + id_estacion + ");");` , so **id_estacion** is not enclosed.

Should be `id_responsable + "','" + id_estacion + '");");`

Comment: You can also remove the < ' > at the left of **id_estacion**, if your datatype is not a varchar.

Comment: You can stop helping fixing this kind of code that leverages to lot of problems and teach how to use `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: already solved. lacked put 'at the end

id_estacion + "');" );

thanks for your help :D

Comment: Please, take a minute to check on @LuiggiMendoza suggestion. It will help you abstract from formatting parameters, and improving code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Your query executes with this string

```
......,'3);
```

which is wrong because you a `'` is missing So either remove it or added matching `'` at the end.

Your string:

```
id_responsable + "','" + id_estacion + ");");
```

Just change it to this :

```
id_responsable + "'," + id_estacion + ");");
```

or

```
id_responsable + "','" + id_estacion + "');");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 + "','" + id_area + "','" + id_responsable + "','" + id_estacion + '");");
```

change last line

Comment: I think you have your quotes the wrong way around - `'");");` should be `"');");`...